# ifstream не работает правильно(c++)

Tags: c++, qt, файлы, fstream

Вот код c qt:

```
int AnswerF;
while(!finAns.eof()){
    finAns>>AnswerF;
    qDebug()<<AnswerF<<"\n";
    VecAnswers.push_back(AnswerF);
    //qDebug()<<VecAnswers[0]<<"\n";
}
//VecAnswers.push_back(2); что должно быть
//VecAnswers.push_back(3);
finAns.close();
```

Он не работает.

Вот программа-тест (без qt):

```
ifstream fin("file.txt");
std::vector<int>VecAnswers;
int AnswerF;
while(!fin.eof()){
    fin>>AnswerF;
    cout<<AnswerF<<"\n";
    VecAnswers.push_back(AnswerF);
    //qDebug()<<VecAnswers[0]<<"\n";
}
fin.close();
```

Она работает.И я задам неожиданный вопрос:*ПОЧЕМУ???*

Comment: не используй `atoi()` — оная не позволяет контролировать ошибки, возьми одно из: `strtol()`, `sscanf()` или `std::stringstream` и проверяй правильность преобразования... по поводу причины ошибки — вангую. что в файле закрался какой-нить невидимый unicode'овский символ — посмотри на файл под hexdump'ом или нормальным редактором в ASCII режиме.

Comment: что вы подразумеваете под "нормальным редактором"

Comment: и вы думаете что я знаю что такое hexdump?

Comment: @Fat-Zer вы правы.Все дело в atoi(); Но я не понимаю почему

Comment: в данном случае нормальный — любой, который поддерживает переключение кодировки и будет адекватно реагировать на символы. которых в ней нет... про hexdump — может не знаешь, может нет под рукой, может ещё-что; ИМХО предложение альтернативного способа лишним не бывает ;)... по существу, сейчас в вопросе какая-то несуразица, так что не знаю что посоветовать...